# React | Using 'parentNode' correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Let's say I have a series of static `div`s that create rows with a handful of children. One of those children has a click handler, which should fire an event specific to its parent `div`. The event needs to target the parent `div` because we're changing some styling *only* in the parent.

Am I correct in how I've targeted each child's `parentNode`, in my code below? (Basically, is this best practice?) Just curious.

Thanks!

```
class ClickExample  extends Component {
  handleClick = (e) => {
    const parentDiv = e.target.parentNode;
    parentDiv.classList.toggle('someClass');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 onClick={(e) => { this.handleClick(e) }}>Click Me!</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 onClick={(e) => { this.handleClick(e) }}>No, Click Me!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClickExample
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is against React philosophy. You should define a component for this purpose. You should read a little bit more of React philosophy but the correct approach would be something like this:

```
class ClickableComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
       return (
           <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
               { this.props.children }
           </div>
       );
    }
}

class ClickExample extends React.Component {

  handleClick() {
      this.setState({
          active: null
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.state.active === 1 ? 'someClass' : null}>
            <ClickableComponent onClick={() => this.setState({ active: 1 })}>
                ClickMe
            </ClickableComponent>            
        </div>
        <div className={this.state.active === 2 ? 'someOtherClass' : null}>
            <ClickableComponent onClick={() => this.setState({ active: 2 })}>
                No, ClickMe!
            </ClickableComponent>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClickExample
```

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't actually solve what I'm asking. In your code, there's still no awareness between `ClickableComponent` and its parent container. I want to change styles of the *direct* parent of my markup with an `onClick`, but your code would simply change styles of the `div` used to wrap the children of `ClickableComponent`, not the *parent* of `ClickableComponent`.

Comment: That's what I meant with react philosophy. children elements should never access parent element directly. I edited my answer to show you how to achieve what you want. `ClickExample` handles the logic of the click in its code and properly adds classes to div containers. `ClickableComponent` now just search for `onClick` in its props and call `ClickExample` logic. SO, the children component does not know anything about its parent but tells when it has been clicked so the parent adjust its style.